# How does a django render function know where this file is located?

Tags: python, django, filesystems

Right so I am following a long a python Django tutorial and I am confused on how this
render function knows where index.html is. The file I am in is views.py.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from appTwo.forms import NewUserForm
def index(request):
    return render(request,'appTwo/index.html')
```

The file structure looks like
[image]

Comment: Because 1. There is a template-root-dir setting in `settings.py`, and 2. You tell it, `'appTwo/index.html'`

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/#configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't "know" per se, but it does scan all template directories you list in settings.py as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES-DIRS). The first that matches the name you provide is used.

Comment: wait im a fool! I forgot I joined the template_dir to the standard base_dir.